# image re-sizing for different platforms

Tags: html, css

I am fairly new to coding and need some help. I have a bootstrap website where the slider does not re-size to mobile devices or tablet sizes. 
The code in the CSS I have added are:

img{ max-width: 100%;}
iframe{ border: 0; width: 100%;}

and

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide us with your code, it will be much easier to answer :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 .img{
   width: ....;
   height: ....;
 }


@media all and (min-width:900px){
  .img{
     width:....;
     height:....;
  }
}
```

so this is css code. the first .img by itself is what it will look like on a phone for example, the @ media tags is what you use to change the size of stuff when the screen size gets above the min-width size. I suggest using firefox as it has a nice responsive view so you can change the screen size to see what it will look like on a smaller screen

Comment: Hi i tried your code but it doesnt work? If you look at the CSS code, i provided a link above can you tell me where i am going wrong?